# Ruby: passing array items into a case statement

Tags: ruby, arrays, case

I am attempting to pass an array into a case statement so I can read the array elements as commands. Unfortunately, it seems that it is not working and the program jumps to the else statement.

```
def input_console()
            quit = 0

    puts "Tell me what you want to do:"

    loop do

        print "\n >>> "
        input = gets.chomp
        sentence = input.split

        case sentence
            when sentence[0] == "go" && sentence[1] == "to"
                puts sentence[2]
            when sentence[0] == "quit"
                quit = 1
            else
                puts "No le entiendo Senor..."
        end
        break if quit == 1
    end
end
```

This piece of code returns "No le entiendo Senor..." whatever you introduce. I expected to get the place I want to go after stating "go to Wherever".

Please, ¿may you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making your case statement independent of a specific variable.

change

```
case sentence
```

to

```
case
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making this a `case` statement?  (And why is `quit` a `Fixnum` rather than a boolean?  Actually, why have it at all?)

```
while true
    # ... prompt and get input ...
    if sentence[0] == "go" && sentence[1] == "to"
        puts sentence[2]
    elsif sentence[0] == "quit"
        break
    else
        puts "No le entiendo Senor..."
    end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `case`?  Isn't it mainly a stylistic issue?

Comment: Mostly stylistic, yes.  `case` might make sense if `sentence[0]` were the only thing you were matching on, but you also want to match on `sentence[1]`, so you had to do `case` without a variable - this isn't much better (and is actually a bit more verbose) than a series of `if ... elsif ... else` blocks.

Comment: I was thinking more of how @Stefan used case (should have clarified). I like case, even when naked, because I generally find it easier to read than if/then/else (less congested and better alignment), and prefer `when A, B, C` to `if A || B || C`. Of course `===` can be very helpful (e.g., `when Fixnum`). Here's a question for you: one often sees `x = case y` and `x = y == 5 ? 4 : 6`, but how often does one see `x = if y==5 then 4 else 6 end`?

Comment: I see your point.  Too much of the Java/C# day job in me to like naked case, I guess.  (You see the last construct quite a bit in Scala for lack of a ternary operator; I don't think I've ever seen it in wild Ruby though.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you would use case-when while checking for values in the array.

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
case 
when a[1] == 2
  p "two"
else
  p "nothing"
end
```

So in your case you can just say

```
case
when sentence[0] == "go" && sentence[1] == "to"
  puts sentence[2]
when sentence[0] == "quit"
  quit = 1
else
  puts "No le entiendo Senor..."  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions. Something like this:

```
case gets
when /\Ago to (.*)\Z/
  puts $1
when /\Aquit\Z/
  # handle quit
else
  puts "No le entiendo Senor..."
end
```

`\A` matches the beginning of string and `\Z` matches just before the trailing newline, so you don't need `chomp`.

Comment: I like the use of a `case` statement here, because `case gets.chomp` gets rid of `input`.