# Pass a Rails variable into a case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm using Rails and have an array that I'm looking to control the output of.

In short, if a project with an ID exists in `@projects`, then I don't want to output the corresponding part of the array, if that exists. So if a project with ID of 1 exists, then I don't want to output `@array[1]`, even if that's present.

The following hardcoded case statement works successfully, to avoid outputting `@array[1]`, `@array[2]` and `@array[3]`:

```
@array.each do |key, value|
  case key when '1','2','3' then
    next # Skip this array key
  end
  # Otherwise, do something else
end
```

But instead of hardcoding `'1','2','3'`, I actually want these to be passed in dynamically, via ActiveRecord. i tried to build a string:

```
@projects_string = @projects.map {|element|
  "'#{element.id}'"
}.join(',')
```

This outputs successfully as `'1','2','3'`. But I can't figure out a way to pass this into the case statement. This fails to match:

```
@array.each do |key, value|
  case key when "#{@projects_string}" then
    next # Skip this array key
  end
  # Otherwise, do something else
end
```

Is there a way to achieve this using this method, or maybe a better way to achieve this using some of Rails' capabilities?

I did look through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006056/ruby-passing-array-items-into-a-case-statement), which seemed most relevant, but couldn't see how to implement it.

Comment: I'm still trying to nail down what you want the output to be. If you have a list of `@products` and you want to see if Project #1 is included, it seems like you basically want to return all projects except #1. Is that correct? What is `@array` in this case?

Comment: How about just an `if` statement that checks if the id exists in `@projects`, instead of a `case` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way as well.

```
@project_arr = @projects.map{|p| p.id.to_s}

@array.each do |key, value|
  unless @project_arr.include?(key.to_s)
    #YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  else
    # SKIP IT
  end
end
```

Comment: I went with this one in the end and it worked right away - perfect, thanks!

Comment: You imply that `@array` is a Ruby Array of projects, but it seems quite a coincidence that the project.id would match the @array index.

[project with id #0, project with id #1, ..., project with id #n]

Is @array really a Ruby Hash?

Comment: I think you may be right - it's an ActiveSupport::OrderedHash

Answer (score 1):

You should not use string but use array and do like

```
@array = Array.new
@array = @projects.map{|arr| arr.id}

@array.each do |key, value|
  if @array.include?(key)
    #code to skip if project is included
  else
    #your code
  end
end
```

Array can be used easily for comparisons than string

Comment: @jon try it and tell me what happens next ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this depends on the type of collection you are dealing with: Array or ActiveRelation.

If they are just arrays and you want elements of `@array` that aren't in @parent, you can just do:

```
@array - @parent
```

If they are both ActiveRecord objects, why not just filter out the `@array` when it's created?

```
@array = Project.where.not(id: @projects.pluck(:id))
```

It seems inefficient (n^2) to have to scan a lookup array (`@projects`) for each element in the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: One is an array (an API response cleaned up and stored in an array) and the other is the ActiveRecord model. I agree if feels inefficient - I need to think of a cleaner way to reuse and clean up the data in time, for sure.

Comment: And you want to basically filter the array based on the AR model?

Comment: I guess duplicating the array, then filtering it to remove any element where the array key matches an AR model ID, would be cleaner? I'd then not need to check the whole AR model each time I try to iterate through the array?

Comment: Although as Steve Wilhelm just mentioned, my 'array' is actually an ActiveSupport::OrderedHash

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
@array = [1,2,3,4]
@projects = [2,3]
@array.each do |key|
  case
  when true === @projects.include?(key)
    next
  end
  puts "Doing something else for #{key}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
Doing something else for 1
Doing something else for 4
```